# regex word boundary excluding the hyphen

Tags: regex

i need a regex that matches an expression ending with a word boundary, but which does not consider the hyphen as a boundary.
i.e. get all expressions matched by

```
type ([a-z])\b
```

but do not match e.g.

```
type a-1
```

to rephrase: i want an equivalent of the word boundary operator \b which instead of using the word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, uses the extended class: `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`

Comment: What regex engine are you using -- is this .NET, javascript, etc.?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use a lookahead for this, the shortest would be to use a negative lookahead:

```
type ([a-z])(?![\w-])
```

`(?![\w-])` would mean "fail the match if the next character is in `\w` or is a `-`".

Here is an option that uses a normal lookahead:

```
type ([a-z])(?=[^\w-]|$)
```

You can read `(?=[^\w-]|$)` as "only match if the next character is **not** in the character class `[\w-]`, or this is the end of the string".

See it working: http://www.rubular.com/r/NHYhv72znm

Comment: In case you also want to match with a space instead of a end or begin of word, you have to add parentheses around the dollar, i.e. ([a-z])(?![\w-])|($|\s). In my case I want to exclude the hyphen from the word boundaries at the beginning and end of a 8 digit number. The regular experssion looked like re.search(r"((?![-\w])|(\s|^))(\d{8})((?![-\w])|(\s|^))", "-12345678 ")

Answer (score 16):

I had a pretty similar problem except I didn't want to consider the '*' as a boundary character.  Here's what I did:

```
\b(?<!\*)([^\s\*]+)\b(?!*)
```

Basically, if you're at a word boundary, look back one character and don't match if the previous character was an '*'.  If you're in the middle, don't match on a space or asterisk.  If you're at the end, make sure the end isn't an asterisk.  In your case, I think you could use \w instead of \s.  For me, this worked in these situations:

```
*word
wo*rd
word*
```

Comment: Your regex has invalid syntax