# Regex matching camelcase words not starting by "."

Tags: regex

I'm trying with grep to find Twig variables that do not respect naming conventions, excluding object properties.
So I would like to match camelCase words, that doesn't start by "."

> does.notMatch
> **doesMatch**
> some words **doesMatch**

I've tried this :

> ^\w+[A-Z]\w+

But it matches only with full lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex word boundary excluding the hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196462/regex-word-boundary-excluding-the-hyphen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want.

But it will work `/(\s|^)(?<!(\.))([a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+)/g` according to your description
[image]

Domo: https://regex101.com/r/3tGe4N/1

Comment: The lookbehind `(?<!(\.))` seems redundant here. If there is `(\s|^)` preceding `[a-z]`, it is already impossible that there occurs a period.

Comment: I am validating the camelcase word which starts with Space/checked is This new Line `(\s|^)` and then checking is this does not start with full-stop using lockbehind `(?<!(\.))`.